# Access data from getServerSideProps in custom document Next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm using getServerSideProps to fetch details of an event. My understanding is that this data will get fetched on the server, then some sort of prerendering will happen, and then a context object is passed into _document.js. I know _document.js will get rendered on every request, but I would like to add a class name to my html if that server data is present (to prevent flashing when doing this client side).

Here is my getServerSideProps function:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const shortId  = context.params.short_id
    const event = await GETrequest({ endpoint: API_PUBLIC_EVENT({ shortId }) })

    return {
        props: {
            event,
            shortId
        } // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
}
```

When I'm within _document.js, I'm able to see that the results of my getServerSideProps are available, as seen when I log the context in getInitialProps like this:

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    console.log(initialProps)
    // can see html that has been processed using my data
}
...
```

I can think of some hacky solutions of getting my className in that initialProps.html, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Is there a way I can structure this so that my data will be more easily available in _document.js, passed from getServerSideProps()?

Comment: Next.js custom [`_document` does not support data fetching methods](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#caveats) like `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`. You should move that logic to your custom `_app` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hacky way to get your page's `getServerSideProps()` data into your `_document.js`, before the app is loaded.

So, as I mentioned you can do some funky stuff with the prerendered html that comes in to use the getServerSideProps() data. This is a hacky solution and very unreliable. In my case however, I'm simply adding a non-consequential className to my document (with a fail-safe on the front-end), so even if this fails everything will be okay.

**Use an abundance of caution if you decide to use this.**

This is how it works:

I have a getServerSideProps() on a page. In this function, I fetch an event and pass it into my page component. In this component, I add an empty div that I know will be rendered, appending the information I need. This information came from my getServerSideProps().

```
<div data-meta-event-theme={event?.theme?.preset}></div>
// let's say theme preset = light
```

Then in my `_document.js`, within a `getInitialProps(ctx)` function, I first check to see if this is a server request. If it's not, skip (build will fail otherwise). Then I check to see if the request is coming from the appropriate route. My route is structured like `/j/[shortId]`, and it's the only page using `/j/`. So before any logic gets triggered, I check to make sure we're on the right page.

```
const isInviteScreen = ctx.req.url.indexOf('/j/') > -1
```

If we're on the right page, then we can parse the value from our html, and do what we want with it.

```
if (isInviteScreen) {
    const html = initialProps.html

    // whatever you set your data to in the html
    // make sure to keep the opening quote "
    const key = 'data-meta-event-theme="'
    
    // you don't have to touch this
    const begin = html.indexOf(key)
    const sub = html.substring(begin + key.length)
    const closingQuote = sub.indexOf('"')
    const value = sub.substring(0, closingQuote)

    console.log(value)
    // logs 'light'
}
```

At this point, I'm able to append that value as a className onto my html, and voila!, no more flashing.

Here is a more full `_document.js`:

```
 class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)

        // Make sure this operation is on the server and has a request
        if (ctx.req) {
            
            // Make sure we're only doing this for the correct route
            const isInviteScreen = ctx.req.url.indexOf('/j/') > -1
            if (isInviteScreen) {
                const html = initialProps.html

                // Your HTML key here, make sure to keep quote
                const key = 'data-meta-event-theme="'

                // Don't have to touch this
                const begin = html.indexOf(key)
                const sub = html.substring(begin + key.length)
                const closingQuote = sub.indexOf('"')

                // Value that was sent from the page with getServerSideProps()
                const value = sub.substring(0, closingQuote)

                return {
                    ...initialProps,
                    preference: { theme: value }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Default return just in case
        return {
            ...initialProps,
            preference: { theme: 'light }
        }
    }

    render() {
        const theme = this.props.preference.theme
        return (
            <Html data-theme={theme} className={theme} lang="en">
                <Head />
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Since this data seems somewhat accessible between the two, I'm hoping there is a more official way to do this?